# Declare a variable as a reference with function that returns a reference

Tags: c++, reference

I have a simple function:

```
vector<float>& myFunction() {
    //> Do something and return a vector<float> (don't worry about scoping now )
}
```

Now somewhere else which is the difference of:

```
vector<float>& myNewVar = myfunction();
             ^
```

versus

```
vector<float> myNewVar = myfunction();  //> Without reference
```

Isn't the second example equivalent to this situation:

```
void myFunction(vector<float>& outVector) {
   //> some code
}

vector<float> myVect;
myFunction(myVect);
```

Comment: The second makes a copy, the first is a reference.

Comment: Doesn't matter. The type of mynewvar is not a reference.

Comment: read [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this version

```
vector<float>& myNewVar = myfunction();
```

`myNewVar` is a *reference* to whatever `myfunction()` returns a reference to.

In this one

```
vector<float> myNewVar = myfunction();
```

`myNewVar` is a *copy* of whatever  `myfunction()` returns a reference to. It takes the reference as input to `std::vector<float>`'s copy constructor.

Perhaps this is illustrated better without a function:

```
int i = 42;

// I want a referennce, so I create one
int& j = i;

// I want a copy, so I make one, even though j is a reference. 
// j is just an alias for i, so k really is a copy of i.
int k = j;
```

Comment: @yes123 no, read the answer carefully. In the first example, no copy is made.

Comment: yes, but to don't make a copy I must declare a reference, whatever the function returns a reference or not

Comment: @yes123 Almost. If the function does not return a reference, you can't really do that, because you would be binding a reference to a temporary, so you would immediately get a dangling reference.

Comment: @yes123 it is not useless at all. Sometimes you really need a reference.

Answer (score 1):

In the second case a copy-ctor is called, in the first case it is not:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() { }
    MyClass(const MyClass & right)
    {
        printf("Copy ctor\n");
    }
};

MyClass & fn()
{
    // Only for the sake of example
    // Please don't complain ;)
    return *(new MyClass());
}

int main(int argc, char * argv)
{
    printf("First case\n");

    MyClass & a = fn();

    printf("Second case\n");

    MyClass b = fn();
}
```

---

**Edit:** In response to your question:

> Isn't the second example equivalent to this situation:

```
void myFunction(vector<float>& outVector) {
   //> some code
}

vector<float> myVect;
myFunction(myVect);
```

It depends. If you don't assign to outVector inside myFunction, copy-ctor won't be called. Difference is minimal, but it does exist.